# ¿Cuál es la palabra en español para "laundry basket"?

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

> ### ¿Cuál es la palabra en español para "laundry basket"?

[image: laundry basket picture]

Comment: I remind you that this is not a site to request translations. Of course the participants of this site can kindly help you with more specific questions about translations that are not clear to you, but we also request that you make a minimum research effort.

Answer (score 3):

Buscando con [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) se obtiene **cesto de la ropa**. Usar un diccionario o un traductor es el primer paso para cuando se quiere una traducción. Y de paso demuestra un mínimo esfuerzo.

Answer (score 3):

También se puede llamar, entre otros;

- **CANASTA PARA LA ROPA SUCIA**
- **CESTO DE LA ROPA SUCIA**
- **CANASTO DE LA ROPA**
- **CAPAZO DE LA ROPA**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que no han mencionado es "cesto de la colada".